# Sources of minifigures with plain, classical faces

Tags: minifigures, shopping

For Reasons™, I am looking for current sets that have minifigures with the plain, classical faces:

[image: classic minifigure]

However, if I look at the [current selection](https://www.lego.com/en-gb/themes/city) on the Lego website, all the accompanying minifigs have stylized faces. The only currently sold set I have seen so far with plain minifigs is [Ikea's BYGGLEK](https://www.ikea.com/us/en/p/bygglek-201-piece-lego-r-brick-set-mixed-colors-30455758/).

Short of hunting for deals for old, retired sets on eBay, are there ways for me to get sets that have plain minifigs?

Comment: (Also, I've last played with Lego as a kid, but only started to get back into it after 25 years, so I'm not hip on what's *de rigueur* these days, and would appreciate some handholding.)

Answer (score 6):

There are several options (moulds) you can choose from:

- [Minifigure, Head Standard Grin Pattern - Hollow Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626cp01) is the latest,
  currently available option. [List of sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626cp01&in=S) with this piece included.
- [Minifigure, Head Standard Grin Pattern - Blocked Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626bp01) was available up until 2016. [List of sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bp01&in=S) with this piece included.
- [Minifigure, Head Standard Grin Pattern - Solid Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626ap01) was available up until 1996. [List of sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626ap01&in=S) with this piece included.

Answer (score 6):

Adding to the answer provided by Alex, there is also the option to buy this head from the pick-a-brick section on the Lego website.

Specifically, part number 9336 "Minifigure, Head Standard Grin Pattern - Hollow Stud" can be found at https://www.lego.com/pick-and-build/pick-a-brick?filters.i0.key=variants.attributes.designNumber&filters.i0.values.i0=9336

Comment: And cheaper than on Bricklink.